# How to spyOn ReduxForm.reset

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, redux-form

When I attempt to spyOn ReduxForm.reset I get an error

```
import * as ReduxForm from 'redux-form';
...
const resetFormSpy = spyOn(ReduxForm, 'reset'); 
// Error: <spyOn> : reset is not declared writable or has no setter
...
expect(resetFormSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I use a similar strategy (`import * as ...`) to spy on other imported functions, and not sure why the failure with `redux-form`.

Is it really that `redux-form` defines `reset` function as non-writable...? (i don't see that declaration in their [code base](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form))